# broadcast receiver issue need help ?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I try to create a broadcast receiver in inner-class of AsyncTask class

here my code

```
public class sendData extends Activity {
    private Intent myFiltered;

    public void send(String loc){
        myFiltered = new Intent(GPS_FILTER);
        myFiltered.putExtra("location_info_post", loc);
        this.sendBroadcast(myFiltered);
    }
}
```

n i call it in onPostExecuted in AysncTask

```
broadCast = new sendData();
        broadCast.send(MyGPS.location_info);
```

I got error as force to stop in my program n this mainly cuz null ponter exception but i don't see any error , any idea??

here my log cat

```
08-01 13:36:03.672: WARN/dalvikvm(509): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
08-01 13:36:03.753: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(509): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-01 13:36:03.753: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(509): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-01 13:36:03.753: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(509):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast(ContextWrapper.java:271)
08-01 13:36:03.753: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(509):     at project.bm.setting.sendGPS$sendData.send(sendGPS.java:108)
08-01 13:36:03.753: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(509):     at project.bm.setting.sendGPS.onPostExecute(sendGPS.java:85)
08-01 13:36:03.753: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(509):     at project.bm.setting.sendGPS.onPostExecute(sendGPS.java:1)
08-01 13:36:03.753: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(509):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
08-01 13:36:03.753: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(509):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
08-01 13:36:03.753: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(509):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
08-01 13:36:03.753: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(509):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-01 13:36:03.753: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(509):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-01 13:36:03.753: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(509):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-01 13:36:03.753: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(509):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-01 13:36:03.753: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(509):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-01 13:36:03.753: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(509):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-01 13:36:03.753: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(509):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-01 13:36:03.753: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(509):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't create Activity like this broadCast = new sendData();

Comment: actually i declare broadCast as member of class type class sendData so it's ok to declare like that

Comment: Activities are opened through Intent. You shouldn't create them manually.

Comment: but what i want to do is just create a broadcast receiver and sendBroadcast it out but my inner class must be activity

Comment: No you just have to get context instance and make broadcast from whatever class you want

Comment: can u give me some example since i just start coding with android

Comment: Ok. you can get Context instance by calling getApplicationContext() from Activity. Than you can use this instance to send broadcast.

Comment: so do i need to create an object to use method send in my case?? can u modify it thx

Comment: I can't do it. Sorry. It is not about I'm snob. Code is completelly wrong. You should think about archetecture of the app. It would be more usefull to read bsic tutorials thirst. It takes not so much time but it can help. Really.

Comment: Thx maxim, so if i just want to update my interface when doing background got the result can i use onProgressUpdate method to initial value static in my UI class?

Comment: In AsyncTask you can do it in onProgressUpdate  and onPostExecute. To have context instance you can get it through AsyncTask constructor param or param of doInBackground (but first variant is much better)